# How to pass data from one form to another form on a different page in laravel 5.7?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want to pass an email value in a textbox from welcome page to register page in Laravel without using the database. I tried the following code in simple PHP page it works fine but when I use in Laravel 5.7 page it shows an error.

**Welcome page**

```
<form method="POST" action="register">
  <input type="text" size="40" name="email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Register Page**

```
<form method="POST" action="register">
  <input type="email" size="40" name="reg_email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">

  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want that when I write an email in welcome page form textbox & submit, it shows or display in a register page form email textbox without using Database.

Comment: You are missing the [csrf token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-introduction) , try adding `@csrf` to both forms.

Comment: Which kind of error message is shown?

Comment: Hi, @Remul thanks for the help, I will check.

Comment: Hi @Nico Hasse thanks for the help,  it shows the following error,

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: Hi @Remul thanks for the help, you give me the right answer.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not to the comment section.

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase, next time I put all relevant information to the question. I got the answer now. Thanks for answering me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send the email as a query string parameter to the registration page.

```php
<!-- Welcome Page (Note the GET method) -->
<form method="GET" action="/register">
    <input type="text" size="40" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Make sure you're including the csrf token in your request.

```php
<!-- Registration Page -->
<form method="POST" action="/register">
    @csrf
    <input type="email" size="40" name="reg_email" value="{{ request('email') }}">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
'''' Welcome page: where user would enter the email before proceeding to registration page

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('welcome') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="text" size="40" name="email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


'''' Register Page: this is where the email displays inside the input name reg_email 

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="email" size="40" name="reg_email" value="{{ $myemail }}">

  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

 //the controller collects the email input from the welcome page
public function Welcome(Request $request)
{
  $email = $request->input('email');
  $data['myemail']=$email; //assign the email variable myemail data to be pass to registration page view
  return view('registerpage',$data);  //pass the data to the view

}

//Route
Route('/welcome-page','MyController@Welcome')->name('welcome'); //ofcourse the route using name route welcome
```

Comment: Hi @Julius Fasema, Thanks for the help.

Comment: uwc. if you fine it helpful, you have to vote the answer

Comment: Hi @Julius Fasema, I voted  it but it shows the message,

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
 
My reputations are only 11.

Comment: its ok! it for sake of other users so that they would know that the answer is helpful and they can make use of it.

Comment: Ya it's true. It is useful for others as like me.   :)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: i only modified the poster code. any for educational purpose let me explain

Comment: Hi @Julius Fasema, I told you 7 days ago that, I was not able to because I had 11 Reputations. Now I just had 16 Reputations, so I am able to vote now. I voted for your answer. Thanks for helping me.